# CUDA thrust remove_if with operlapping stencil sequence

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I was trying to remove elements from two `thrust::device_vector<int>` based on the values of the first vector. Intuitively I created the following snipped:

```
thrust::device_vector<float> idxToValue(COUNT_MAX);
thrust::device_vector<int> idxSorted(COUNT_MAX);
thrust::device_vector<int> groupIdxSorted(COUNT_MAX);
int count = COUNT_MAX;
float const minThreshold = MIN_THRESHOLD;

auto idxToValueSortedIter = thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
    idxToValue.begin()
    , idxSorted.begin()
    );

auto new_end = thrust::remove_if(
    thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(idxSorted.begin(), groupIdxSorted.begin()))
    , thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(idxSorted.begin() + count, groupIdxSorted.begin() + count))
    , idxToValueSortedIter 
    , thrust::placeholders::_1 >= minThreshold
    );

count = thrust::get<0>(new_end.get_iterator_tuple()) - idxSorted.begin();
```

The Thrust documentations unfortunately says

> The range [stencil, stencil + (last - first)) shall not overlap the range [result, result + (last - first))

So in my case `idxToValueSortedIter`, which is used as stencil sequence, depends on `idxSorted` and is in fact overlapping the result (same vector).

Is there any way to solve this without copying the data to a temporary vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this just by using the non-stencil version of `remove_if` (having no stencil, it has no such restriction on the overlap of the stencil with the output sequence), and passing your stencil (i.e. your permutation iterator) as a 3rd member of your `zip_iterator` to `remove_if` plus an appropriate selection functor.  Here is a worked example:

```
$ cat t572.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/remove.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

#define COUNT_MAX 10
#define MIN_THRESHOLD 4.5f

struct my_functor
{
  float thresh;
  my_functor(float _thresh): thresh(_thresh) {}

  template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(T &mytuple) const {
    return thrust::get<2>(mytuple) > thresh;
  }
};

int main(){

  float h_idxToValue[COUNT_MAX] = {0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f, 8.0f, 9.0f};
  int   h_idxSorted[COUNT_MAX] = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
  int   h_groupIdxSorted[COUNT_MAX] = {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29};

  thrust::device_vector<float> idxToValue(h_idxToValue, h_idxToValue + COUNT_MAX);
  thrust::device_vector<int> idxSorted(h_idxSorted, h_idxSorted + COUNT_MAX);
  thrust::device_vector<int> groupIdxSorted(h_groupIdxSorted, h_groupIdxSorted + COUNT_MAX);
  int count = COUNT_MAX;
  float const minThreshold = MIN_THRESHOLD;

  auto new_end = thrust::remove_if(
    thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(idxSorted.begin(), groupIdxSorted.begin(), thrust::make_permutation_iterator(idxToValue.begin(), idxSorted.begin())))
    , thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(idxSorted.begin() + count, groupIdxSorted.begin() + count, thrust::make_permutation_iterator(idxToValue.begin(), idxSorted.begin() + count)))
    , my_functor(minThreshold)
    );

  count = thrust::get<0>(new_end.get_iterator_tuple()) - idxSorted.begin();

  std::cout << "count = " << count << std::endl;
  thrust::copy_n(groupIdxSorted.begin(), count, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -std=c++11 -o t572 t572.cu
$ ./t572
count = 5
25,26,27,28,29,
$
```

We would normally expect the `remove_if` function with the supplied functor to remove entries whose `idxToValue` value was greater than the threshold (4.5).  However, due to the permutation iterator and the reverse ordering sequence in `idxSorted`, we see that the values above the threshold are *retained* and the others are removed.  The above example was with CUDA 6.5 and Fedora 20 to take advantage of the experimental c++11 support.

Comment: I was actually looking for a way avoiding a custom functor (i.e. by using placeholders), but it's what I asked for and it works! Thanks!